# Powershell Crashes immediately after opening

Tags: powershell

I have been learning `react.js` by writing some code in vc code, after finishing my code I tried to run the code via terminal suddenly terminal closes by showing some error, then I ran PowerShell separately from start it also showed the same error and closed.

Here is the error it showed:

```
Unhandled exception: SystemAccessViolationException : Attempted to read or write protected memory. This often an indication of memory is corrupt.
```

Comment: Restart the system and try again? Or try a sfc /scannow. Just basing this off the error

Comment: Check your "profile" script - it's a startup script that PowerShell automatically runs every time it starts. Chances are there's something in there that's blowing up. There are multiple locations a profile script can live - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-5.1 for all the possible locations.

Comment: Where to see this profile script @mclayton

Comment: See the link in my previous comment. You can also use the ```-NoProfile``` switch on the command line to disable the profile for that session. That will prove whether it’s a profile issue or not.